# MySQL select last record and update it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to select the last record in the table and update its name.

```
UPDATE item 
SET name = (SELECT name FROM pds
            WHERE id = 9)
WHERE id=(SELECT id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

However, when executing name is changed for all the records.

Tried also:

```
UPDATE item 
SET name = (SELECT name FROM pds
            WHERE id = 9)
WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM item ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: `WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM item);` maybe?

Comment: @Dacaspex I get the same error as for my second query (Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'item' for update in FROM clause
)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In MySQL you can apply `order by` and `limit` clauses to an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE item 
SET name = (SELECT name FROM pds
            WHERE id = 9)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `limit` and `order by`:

```
update item
    set name = (select name from pds where id = 9)
    order by id desc
    limit 1;
```

Your second version should work . . . except MySQL probably generates a syntax error.  Try:

```
UPDATE item i CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT MAX(i2.id) as maxid FROM item i2) mi
    SET i.name = (SELECT pds.name FROM pds WHERE pds.id = 9)
    WHERE i.id = mi.maxid;
```

The first version is syntactically correct, but it has no `FROM` clause, so it is using the `id` value from the outer query -- and just checking that the `id` is equal to itself.  When using subqueries in the `select` or `where` clauses, *always* use qualified column names.  I advise doing this all the time, but this is especially important for subqueries in these clauses.